# elasticsearch query using pyspark and elasticsearch-hadoop connector throws exception in RecordReader.close

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, pyspark

Reading from elasticsearch into rdd throws exception:

org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no scroll ids specified;]

And

mr.EsInputFormat: Cannot determine task id...

Software versions: pyspark 1.6,  elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.1 connector used as connector to elasticsearch, Elasticsearch version is 1.0.1 , hadoop 2.7.2 and python 2.7

elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.1 library taken from here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/2.2/reference.html

**Code**:

```
es_rdd =  sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
conf={ "es.resource" : "INDEX/TYPE", "es.nodes" : "NODE_NAME"})
print (es_rdd.first())
```

Please help to resolve the exception;

The following warning is printed before the exception, Could be linked to this warning and potentially the actual exception:
mr.EsInputFormat: Cannot determine task id...

INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id

**Full Exception**:

16/04/26 21:00:02 INFO rdd.NewHadoopRDD: Input split: ShardInputSplit [node=[KHHV8pgMQySzw9Fz1Xt7VQ/Iguana|135.17.42.49:9200],shard=0]
16/04/26 21:00:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
16/04/26 21:00:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
16/04/26 21:00:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id

16/04/26 19:31:12 WARN mr.EsInputFormat: Cannot determine task id...
16/04/26 19:31:14 WARN rdd.NewHadoopRDD: Exception in RecordReader.close()
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no scroll ids specified;]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:478)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:449)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.deleteScroll(RestClient.java:512)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.close(ScrollQuery.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat$ShardRecordReader.close(EsInputFormat.java:262)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$rdd$NewHadoopRDD$$anon$$close(NewHadoopRDD.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:110)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)

Thank you !